# scopeAttributes with multiple values

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I'm using the [Strip-Whitespace-On-Save](https://github.com/bomberstudios/Strip-Whitespace-On-Save.tmbundle) & [Ensure-Newline-At-The-EOF](https://github.com/hajder/Ensure-New-Line-at-the-EOF.tmbundle) bundles.

Now there are some files for which I don't want anything to automatically happen (I'm testing with CSV, since it's sooo delicate).

I've tried the following .tm_properties settings :

```
[*.csv]
scopeAttributes = attr.keep-whitespace
scopeAttributes = attr.do-not-ensure-new-line
```

which results in the following attributes (`⌃⇧P`) :

```
attr.do-not-ensure-new-line
```

ie. the first attribute disappears. Reversing the order (expectedly) makes the other attribute show up. Having two separate `[*.csv]` sections, results in the same behavior.

Using those settings :

```
[*.csv]
scopeAttributes = attr.keep-whitespace,attr.do-not-ensure-new-line
```

results in a `attr.keep-whitespace,attr.do-not-ensure-new-line` attribute, which the bundles ignore. Adding curly braces around the `scopeAttributes` value just makes the curly braces show up (eg. `{attr.keep-whitespace,attr.do-not-ensure-new-line}`).

I've looked around in docs and gists, but every example I've seen only does single attributes at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify both scopes separated by a space (and then you need to quote the whole thing, to make sure it’s parsed correctly):

```
[*.csv]
scopeAttributes = "attr.keep-whitespace attr.do-not-ensure-new-line"
```